# What is the difference between onmouseenter and simply mouseenter? I can't seem to use onmouseenter with .addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, onmouseover

What is the difference between `onmouseenter` and simply `mouseenter`? I can't seem to use `onmouseenter` with `.addEventListener`?

Comment: `onmouseenter` is an attribute of the HTML Element while `mouseenter` is the name of an Event. `addEventListener` requires as first parameter an event, therefore you have to use `mouseenter`

Comment: @secan So when would i use onmouseenter?

Comment: `onmouseenter` is only one function is bound to the event. but `addEventListener` can be more

Comment: @cool-peaches It is not *when* but *how*; you can use either of them but in different ways: `yourElement.onmouseenter = function() { ... }` or `yourElement.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {...})`